# BeautifulSoup Find periodically returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a value from a class. From time to time, find returns the value I need, but another time it no longer works.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://beru.ru/catalog/molotyi-kofe/76321/list'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                         '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

item_count = (soup.find('div', class_='_2StYqKhlBr')).text.split()[4]

print(item_count)
```

Comment: the [4] is causing None to be returned at times. Your `text` might have less than 5 elements

Comment: That is not the problem. Even if I try to get `item_count = (soup.find('div', class_='_2StYqKhlBr')).text`— periodically returns None.

Comment: @NikitaBiryukov check my answer below to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why that you get the values sometimes and sometimes not. That's because the website is protected by `CAPTCHA`

So when the request is blocked by `CAPTCHA`

It's became like the following:

```
https://beru.ru/showcaptcha?retpath=https://beru.ru/catalog/molotyi-kofe/76321/list?ncrnd=4561_aa1b86c2ca77ae2b0831c4d95b9d85a4&t=0/1575204790/b39289ef083d539e2a4630548592a778&s=7e77bfda14c97f6fad34a8a654d9cd16
```

You can verify by parse the response content:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(
    'https://beru.ru/catalog/molotyi-kofe/76321/list')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': '_2StYqKhlBr _1wAXjGKtqe'}):
    print(item)

for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'captcha__image'}):
    for captcha in item.findAll('img'):
        print(captcha.get('src'))
```

And you will get the `CAPTCHA` image link:

```
https://beru.ru/captchaimg?aHR0cHM6Ly9leHQuY2FwdGNoYS55YW5kZXgubmV0L2ltYWdlP2tleT0wMEFMQldoTnlaVGh3T21WRmN4NWFJRUdYeWp2TVZrUCZzZXJ2aWNlPW1hcmtldGJsdWU,_0/1575206667/b49556a86deeece9765a88f635c7bef2_df12d7a36f0e2d36bd9c9d94d8d9e3d7
```

Comment: @NikitaBiryukov you welcome, if you found it useful, so accept the answer :)